# Does the Page_SchemaGenerator class work in Agiletoolkit?

Tags: atk4

I am looking at atk4 (http://agiletoolkit.org/) for a project.

However the Page_SchemaGenerator is not working for me:

```
Method is not defined for this object


Additional information:

Raised by object: Object Model_Testmodel(igSchool_create_model_testmodel)
class: Model_Testmodel
method: getAllFields
arguments: Array ( )
```

Can someone confirm if it works in atk4 4.2?

Comment: It's not working for 4.2 yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update has been pushed to atk4-adddons master branch.

update your atk4-adddons to latest version and it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I see it's a work in progress, but a very handy tool for getting started